# Detect planes of a room with corners using arcore and sceneform in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm working on an AR application and what I'm trying to achieve is to detect all horizontal and vertical planes, including corners so that I have the basic structure of a room. Using ARCore and Sceneform I can distinguish between a vertical plane and a horizontal but to pinpoint a corner seems impossible to me. Is there any workaround so that I can detect the whole room with corners?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply some computer vision to this. What I would do is record the images and the point cloud associated with each image along with the camera pose for each image.

Then, I will apply the Harris corner detector on each image and project the point cloud for that image. Some points from the projected point cloud will lie on the detected corners.

Do this for several images and you will have a lot of points from the point clouds clustered around just the corners. You may have to adjust some parameters for the Harris corner detector to get good corners.