# Is there a way to measure the area of a room using Augmented Reality in flutter?

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am developing an app in Flutter that is connecting to ARKit and ARCore to initiate an augmented reality session with the aim of measuring distances to determine the area of a room. Specifically it aims at determining the distance between three edges of a room and finally to determine the height of a wall.

I am new to Augmented reality and couldn't find any materials or tutorials related to the topic. If anyone can guide me with this that will be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70808209/2287994) to determine all corners of a room and then try to [fit a rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2712935/509735) that covers all the detected corners on the floor. The area for this rectangle is the area of the room. For the height of the room, the largest vertical distance between any two anchors in your room will give you the height.